# Prevent creating observable in subscribe Rxjava

Tags: rx-java, reactive-programming, retrofit2, rx-android

I'm new to RxJava and got a problem. Here's my code to get list of A :

```
 Utils.getRetrofit().create(StoryAPI.class).getCategories() // Observable<Wrapper<List<A>>>
     .map(Wrapper::getResult) // List<A>
     .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
     .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
     .subscribe(list -> {
        Observable.range(0, list.size())
           .subscribe(m -> {
               menu.add(2, list.get(m).getId(), m + 6, list.get(m).getName());
            }, Logger::logException);
      }, Logger::logException);
```

Is there any way to prevent nested Observable like this, and move the `Observable.range` outside the `subscribe()`

Answer (score 0):

### flatMap and Observable.from()

```
 // define i
 int i = 0;


  Utils.getRetrofit().create(MyAPI.class).getList() // got Observable<Wrapper<List<A>>>
 .map(Wrapper::getResult) // Wrapper to List<A>
 .flatMap(listResult->Observable.from(listResult))
 .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
 .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
 .subscribe(result->{
      menu.add(2,result.getId(),i+6,result.getName());
      i++;
   });
```

Comment: But in subscribe, result is the A, not the List<A> as expected

Comment: Why do you use List<A> in `subscribe`?

Comment: To insert them to the menu, I need the index of an item in the list

Comment: you should explain your code clearly and express your idea.Can you complete `doSomethingElse`?